# How can I call Vim from Python?

Tags: python, vim

I would like a Python script to prompt me for a string, but I would like to use Vim to enter that string (because the string might be long and I want to use Vim's editing capability while entering it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


from __future__ import print_function

from os import unlink
from tempfile import mkstemp
from subprocess import Popen


def callvim():
    fd, filename = mkstemp()

    p = Popen(["/usr/bin/vim", filename])
    p.wait()

    try:
        return open(filename, "r").read()
    finally:
        unlink(filename)


data = callvim()
print(data)
```

**Example:**

```
$ python foo.py 
This is a big string.

This is another line in the string.

Bye!
```

Answer (score 4):

You can call vim with a file path of your choice:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["vim","hello.txt"])
```

Now you can use this file as your string:

```
file = open("hello.txt", "r")
aString = file.read()
```

Comment: Is Vim guaranteed to flush to the file before call() returns?

Comment: @jl6: nice question. I don't think there is a guarantee because it is the operating system's cup of tea when the data is physically flushed to the file. But I assume that you will call open() after call() and that the OS is fair enough to finish the write action before opening the file in read mode.

Comment: @jl6: btw, I would prefer James answer. It's pretty convenient.